# Can't Read File After Building in java

Tags: java, file, netbeans

hey guys i've this program to read a file

```
public static String readFileAsString(String filename){
    BufferedReader reader;
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
        String line;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        reader.close();
        return sb.toString();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File Not Found","ERROR",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    } catch (IOException ex) {  
        Logger.getLogger(tsst.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }  
    return null;
  }
```

and this is my constructor

```
public tsst() {
    initComponents();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, readFileAsString("test.txt"),"Succes",JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION);
}
```

and the file is in the application project if i run the file from Netbeans it's work normaly i got what i need but if i build the application so i got the JAR File and i run it i got Error FILE NOT FOUND 
and the same in the Writing

```
public static void writeFile(String canonicalFilename, String text){
  File file = new File (canonicalFilename);
  BufferedWriter out; 
      try {
         out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
         out.write(text);
         out.close();
     } catch (IOException ex) {
         Logger.getLogger(tsst.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
     }
}
```

Comment: Where is the file located relative to your project?

Comment: With NetBeans, readable files usually need to be in the top directory of the project (along with src/ and build/ and others like that)

Comment: when you execute the jar directly, the jar and the file that you want to read or write to have to be at the same location( in same directory ). Or you have to pass the filename along with the path to FileReader.

Comment: C:\Users\Samer\Documents\NetBeansProjects\testApp the File is located here @MadProgrammer

Comment: if i did this readFileAsString("C:\\Users\\Samer\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\testApp\\test.txt"); 
it works @MarkDacek but this is not what i m looking for beacause i want that my application will be installed in an other PC you get it ?? please any other ideas ?

Comment: So, in order to read a file, you need to provide an appropriate path to it.  In your case `readFileAsString("test.txt")` is saying, please read the file which located in the current working directory (usually where the Jar file is located)

Answer (score 1):

Add this line in your readFileAsString method

```
System.out.println("Current Directory:"+ new File(".").getAbsolutePath());
```

That will tell you what your application's current directory is. Put your test.txt file in that same directory and you should be able to read it. I'd imagine the output would be different between Netbeans (where you know the file is expected) and when you run the Jar (which could be anywhere).